# how to convert string stored in list into utf8?

Tags: python-3.x

i have tokenized the text form the text files stored in a list and stored the tokenized text in a variable and when i print that variable it shows the wrong result.

```py
import glob

files = glob.glob("D:\Pakistan Constitution\*.txt")

documents = []

for file in files:

    with open(file) as f:

        documents.append(f.read())

stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())

texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in documents]

print(texts)
```

I expect the tokenized words but result occur is like that

> ['ÿþp\x00a\x00r\x00t\x00', '\x00v\x00', '\x00', '\x00r\x00e\x00l\x00a\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00s\x00', '\x00b\x00e\x00t\x00w\x00e\x00e\x00n\x00',

So anyone can help me regarding this

Comment: Do you know the encoding of your files? May you set it explicitly?

Comment: It looks like the files are encoded as UTF16, specifically UTF16LE.  The very first characters `ÿþ` in the output are what you would get if you treated the UTF16 Little-Endian Byte Order Mark `\xFF\xFE` as UTF8 characters.

Comment: how do i overcome that problem